# How do I Inject one interface in another service in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I want to Inject one interface in another serviceimpl.

```
@Service
class ServiceA implements InterfaceA {
 //// 
}

@Service
class ServiceB implements InterfaceB {
  @Inject
  private InterfaceA obj; // returning null
}
```

The above structure returning null when I am trying to use InterfaceA in ServiceB.
I even tried with @Lazy like below,

```
  @Inject
  @Lazy
  private InterfaceA obj; // returning null
```

Comment: Try with @Autowired.

Comment: An autowired field in spring cannot be `null`, your application will fail to start. Which means you are probably doing a `new ServiceB()` yourself or at least outside the scope of Spring.